# Why do I need to type this command twice for it to work in Typescript, Ionic 2?

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

I've been searching for 2 hours on the problem that, my callback function doesn't dismiss the LoadingController in Ionic 2.

I have a function, hideLoading():

```
hideLoading()
{
    this.loader.dismiss();
}
```

Which is called in the success function

```
connectionSuccess = () =>
{
    this.hideLoading();

    var toast = Toast.create({
        message: '...',
        duration: 3000});

    this.nav.present(toast);
}
```

For some reason it doesn't work.. But I just found out that it works -- if I put an alert() in between; or if I change the code to this:

```
connectionSuccess = () =>
{
    this.hideLoading();
    this.loader.dismiss();
    [...] 
}
```

Is it some time-related error? The time of the alert() in between or the second hide instruction seems to fix it.. I checked the contents of `this.loader` in console logs before dismissing and it is perfectly right.

If I remove one of the two instructions above, it doesn't work. It needs the two instructions -- which basically do the same thing, but only work together..?

This is a pretty dirty fix. How could I fix this in a clean manner? I don't understand why it's behaving so unpredictably.

Comment: What is `this.loader`, what does calling `dismiss` on it return? `undefined`? A `Promise`? An `Observable`? You may be missing an `await`, a `return`, or a `subscribe` but it is hard to tell from the information provided.

Comment: @AluanHaddad `this.loader` is an instance of the `Loading` class of the `ionic-angular` for Ionic 2. The `dismiss()` method returns `ZoneAwarePromise {...}`. Await sounds good, but I get a syntax error putting an await in front of the method call. It does seem to be an async/await issue since putting an alert in between solves it.. **Edit: I tried the alert() and it doesn't fix it anymore.. But just before, it worked using an alert() between**.

Comment: Okay so it returns a Promise, then use `async hideLoading() { await this.loader.dismiss(); }` then you need to await that in the method that calls `hideLoading`. You can also use `then` and explicitly return the result. await is the more readable option.

Comment: FYI, the reason alert works is probably because alert is one of those rare browser APIs that actually blocks the event loop.

Comment: @AluanHaddad I changed the target to ES6 to use async/await. I then added the async/await to the hideLoading() function, and I call it like this: `await this.hideLoading();` -> however I get syntax errors on this, it doesn't want to run. The success function isn't an async function. It is worth noting that it works perfectly in the error function, but doesn't want to work in the success function.

Comment: Not sure why, maybe you are not using the latest TypeScript (use >=2.2.1). Anyway, you can accomplish the same task without `async`/`await` with `.then` and `.catch`

Comment: @AluanHaddad I put `this.loader.dismiss().then(null, null);` however it still doesn't work (it is not dismissed), are you sure? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Because the null is wrong. Let me post an answer.

Comment: Added answer with sample code for both approaches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on discussion, carried out in comments, we know that `this.Loader` is an instance of a an ionic-angular `Loading` class, and that its `dismiss` method returns, at least when run in the OP's context, a `ZoneAwarePromise` instance.

`ZoneAwarePromise` is a specialized `Promise` implementation created for, and returned by, the **zone.js** the library which Angular depends on to subvert the DOM and rewire the orchestration of asynchronous of callbacks and events, but I digress...

The point is that it is basically a `Promise`, and definitely indicates an *asynchronous* API. We need to talk to such an API appropriately as using it in a fire and forget manner can cause timing issues such as the behavior indicated by in the OP.

Below I will illustrate what I believe to be, based on the OP's code, correct rewrites of that code.

1. In TypeScript >= 2.2.0 and ES2017, we have two approaches we can leverage to cleanly and correctly handle promise based APIs and ensure the correct execution order of dependent logic.

   `async`/`await`. This can be considered the preferred way to interact with Promise based APIs going forward as it offers exceptional readability and allows for standard exception handling model. It is also extremely concise and pleasant to write.

   ```
   export default class {

     async hideLoading() {
       // note we probably don't need the try wrapper
       // it is good practice to NOT handle unknown errors
       // just put it here for illustrative purposes
       try {
         await this.loader.dismiss();
       } 
       catch (e) {
         console.error(e);
       }
     }

     connectionSuccess = async () => {
       await this.hideLoading();

       const toast = Toast.create({
         message: '...',
         duration: 3000
       });

       this.nav.present(toast);
     };

   }
   ```
2. In older versions of TypeScript, `async`/`await` was only supported for `--target es2015`. If we need to target `es5` and have an old version of TypeScript that we cannot upgrade (you really should upgrade if at all possible), then we can write the above code with the same semantics in the following manner

   ```
   export default class {

     hideLoading() {
       // note we probably don't need the .catch call
       // it is good practice to NOT handle unknown errors
       // just put it here for illustrative purposes
       return this.loader.dismiss()
         .catch(e => console.error(e));
     }

     connectionSuccess = () => {
       this.hideLoading()
         .then(() => {
           const toast = Toast.create({
             message: '...',
             duration: 3000
           });

           this.nav.present(toast);
         });
     };

   }
   ```

The key takeaway here is that when we are talking to an asynchronous API we must use an asynchronous programming model. If the API is Promise based, like the one here, then using it via `async`/`await` is an almost effortless change as we can even retain sequential exception handling mechanisms.

If we do not have `async`/`await` support in either our transpiler or our runtime, we can accomplish the same goal using `Promise.prototype.then` and `Promise.prototype.catch` to write code that gets the job done with minimal fuss.

If the API were `Observable` based, then we would need a more complex transformation and would not have the option of using syntactic sugar such as `async`/`await`.<sup>1</sup>

Notes:

1. In RxJS' languages of origin, C# and Visual Basic, both `async`/`await` *and* LINQ comprehensions are available directly on `Observable`s as syntactic sugar for manipulating. They may not be the perfect fit but this can be helpful. In JavaScript we have no such facilities.

Comment: This worked for me, thanks a lot! I was unaware of how the .then() should be used, but it makes a lot of sense now.

Comment: Glad I could help